# Need help for migrating authentication to OAuth2.0 in google analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics

I am currently using Google management API for analytics v2.4, but the way i do the authentication is deprecated (function setUserCredentials), so I need to migrate to OAuth2.0 authentication, but I am having some problems to understand google documentation, about it.

```
        DataQuery query = new DataQuery(new URL(DATA_URL));
        query.setIds(tableId);
        query.setStartDate(startDate);
        query.setEndDate(endDate);
        query.setDimensions(dimensions);
        query.setMetrics(metrics);
        query.setMaxResults(10000);
        query.setStringCustomParameter("key", "API_key");

        return query;
    }

    private static DataFeed getDataFeed(String username, String password, String startDate, String endDate, String dimensions, String metrics) throws ServiceException, IOException {

        AnalyticsService myService = new AnalyticsService("xxxxxx");

        myService.setUserCredentials(username, password);

        DataQuery query = getQuery(GA_ID, startDate, endDate, dimensions, metrics, 1);
        DataFeed data = null;
        try{
            data = myService.getFeed(query, DataFeed.class);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Can I still use the v2.4 and do the authentication with OAuth2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that the [v2.4 API is also deprecated](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/migration-guide). If it isn't already shutdown it might be without warning.

If you already have rewrite your code because of the auth issue, you should upgrade to Analytics Reporting API v4 and Analytics Management API v3. See the quick [start](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4#quick_start_guides) 
 [guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3#next).